# How to inject SLF4J bindings with Guice?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice, slf4j

After a cursory inspection, it seems like SLF4J and Guice (well, any DI framework, really) are sort of conflicting philosophies. SLF4J takes the approach "*hey, we won't know until runtime what classes we're going to bind to, and that's OK.*" Guice, on the other hand, seems to say "*hey, we need to know at compile-time exactly what classes we're binding to.*".

So I ask: is it possible to use Guice/Spring/whatever DI framework to configure/inject SLF4J bindings?

The kicker is that the Java `ClassLoader` is what is really "injecting" SLF4J at runtime with the proper Logger/LoggerFactory/etc. objects, so I can't figure out how to inject those ClassLoaders so that they returns the `org.slf4j.impl.Logger` that I want at runtime:

I ask because I like the benefit of SLF4J and logging against an API, but also like the benefits of DI. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to use Guice to inject `Logger`? Inject `LoggerFactory`? Bind `LoggerFactory` to a particular API implementation based on a Guice configuration? (I haven't worked with SLF4J before but from what I can tell all three are viable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is not possible (unless you make something extremely cumbersome, like a container that create child classloader for your app... something like that)

The basic idea of SLF4j to have replaceable implementation is by having the binder lib providing the `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` and SLF4J API will lookup this class thru classloader.  Hence, if there is more than 1 binder in classpath, there is no way to distinguish the `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`s they are providing.  DI framework is not going to help on this, given that Logging framework initialize even before DI happens.

Unless SLF4J is changing its design in the future, there is not much way we can do.  And, I doubt it is possible even SLF4J changes its design.  As we have no way to tell the DI container that the Logging initialization is something everybody depends on.  I believe there are more reasons make it almost impossible to achieve.

However, what I am in doubt is, does this really have to do with DI?  Honestly I don't see the problem of controlling which logging binding to use by putting corresponding JAR in classpath.  If you want to control it on runtime, kind of programmatically, I think writing a little container to launch your app is the way to go.  However, it is still nothing to do with DI.

Answer (score 1):

One rather simple approach to this problem is to inject a `ILoggerFactory` instance into `LoggerFactory` via the `setILoggerFactory()` method. (As of October 2012, the `setILoggerFactory()` method does not exist.)

The static binding mechanism currently implemented by SLF4J does not do much other than setting the `ILoggerFactory`. Would such an approach work for you?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this now: [Sangria](https://github.com/tavianator/sangria) implements a "context-sensitive binder" that works very well for this; see `sangria-slf4j` and `sangria-contextual` specifically.

From [the author's blog post](https://tavianator.com/announcing-sangria/), you can set up an SLF4J named logger factory as easily as:

```
public class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new SangriaSlf4jModule());
    }
}
```

...and there are examples of how to use the new providers for your own types as well.

Comment: OP is not asking for injecting Loggers with name according to context.  He is asking for even switching implementation (aka binding) of SLF4j.

Comment: Excellent find. Thanks for posting this!